# Preload & site preformance: x amount of PDF's vs x * amount of pages PNG's

Tags: performance, pdf, png, preloader

I have a question.

I am currently developing a website and I am nearly finished with the gallery section. The gallery section will display either a) a pdf file or b) several pngs(these pngs will be displayed under each other, it will look just like the pdf) when a user clicks on one of the gallery pictures.

I have the option of choosing between as said PDF or png.

The problem is the pdf files are up towards 5mb and I cannot do anything about this. I was thinking of preloading the pdf files or pngs in advance.

I am looking for one thing: site preformance.

Is it better to preload the one pdf (there will be up towards 20-30 pdfs in this gallery, so I will be preloading 20-30 pdf's) or is it better to go with the png approach (20-30*x amount of pages).

Or if anyone else has a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

The best criteria will be to try, measure and see for yourself.

In any case, you might try to reduce the load by finding balance between amount of pre-loaded data and simplicity and load.

In case of PNGs you might try to split images into smaller parts and preload only images required to display one or two first pages. This will allow visitor to quickly open those pages (he might not go farther after all).

In case of PDFs you might linearize documents (optimize them for Fast Web View). For linearized documents you might try to preload beginning of the file only. There is a question about [finding how much you should preload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10097407/249690). Adobe plugin opens linearized files faster then non-linearized. I am not aware about other PDF plugins that make use of this optimization, though.