# How chrome showing pdf even not fully downloaded?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, inputstream

I am using chrome since long time. Today I checked Chrome showing PDF pages while downloading itself. Downloading not even fully completed (20%) but chrome able to paint the few pages which are downloaded.

AFAIK the directly convert stream input to pdf.

[image: Chrome partial shown partial pdf]

I want to know What is the technologies behind this..? How they are achieved it..? I want to replicate the same via programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called linearized PDF, which means that the PDF file is structured in a way that all the resources required by the first page can be downloaded first without downloading the whole file.

This is not something that Chrome implemented (sort of), it is rather a feature of the PDF file itself, and the application who generated it. Chrome will not be able to do the same with non-linearized PDFs.

Take a look at this other question with its answer for some more details: [How can I determine the extent (in bytes) of page 1 in a linearized PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097407/how-can-i-determine-the-extent-in-bytes-of-page-1-in-a-linearized-pdf-file)

Comment: Thanks to open my eyes. I thought its a chrome feature.